# Problems Running Python Script - not being able to run script on windows 11 ubuntu wsl2

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Greetings

**I am running the following code on python3 using Windows 11 WSL2**

```
import sys
import json
import os

#os.system("pip install opencv-python")
#os.system("pip install numpy")
#os.system("pip install urllib3")
os.system("pip install PIL")
os.system("pip install pillow")
os.system("pip install urllib3")
os.system("pip install chardet")

import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image


url1 = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/987617293306859520/T4aHjh5r_400x400.jpg"
url2 = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-JVIkYYRHoW0/Vp-aV0ALdUI/AAAAAAAADhc/huHp_gFx_b4/s1600/IMG_6572.JPG"

def convert_to_grayscale(pic1,pic2):
    gray_img1 = np.array(Image.open(pic1))
    gray_img2 = np.array(Image.open(pic2))
    gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(gray_img1,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(gray_img2,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    return (gray_img1,gray_img2)
 
def url_to_image(url):
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    contents = data.read()
    return contents

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image1 = url_to_image(url1)
    image2 = url_to_image(url2)
    gray_pic1, gray_pic2 = convert_to_grayscale(image1,image2)
    cv2.imshow('Gray scaled image 1',gray_pic1)
    cv2.imshow('Gray scaled image 2',gray_pic2)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

*When I run this piece of code I get the following error:*

**This was my first error log:**

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.8) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bruteForceOpenCV.py", line 34, in <module>
    gray_pic1, gray_pic2 = convert_to_grayscale(image1,image2)
  File "bruteForceOpenCV.py", line 20, in convert_to_grayscale
    gray_img1 = np.array(Image.open(pic1))
  File "/home/tmm88/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2953, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

**now, i am getting the following:**

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /home/tmm88/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (9.0.1)
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /home/tmm88/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.26.8)
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.0.4)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.8) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bruteForceOpenCV.py", line 37, in <module>
    gray_pic1, gray_pic2 = convert_to_grayscale(image1,image2)
  File "bruteForceOpenCV.py", line 23, in convert_to_grayscale
    gray_img1 = np.array(Image.open(pic1))
  File "/home/tmm88/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2953, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

**I am currently being able to:**

- *make an http request for the images*

**I am not being able to:**

- *convert the images to greyscale*
- *bruteforce them and compare them with opencv*

**any help is appreciated**

**can someone please help me to fix this?**

**thank you so much**
*T.*

Answer (score 0):

"No matching distribution found for PIL"

Did you install pillow?

```
$ pip install pillow
$ pip install urllib3
$ pip install chardet
```

After you did it, close terminal and try again.

If you don't know what packages you have installed, you must run:

```
$ pip list
```

or if you want it in a txt file...

```
$ pip list > mypackages.txt
```

Hope I helped you.